# How to store an object that is accessible throughout the app's life is iOS using Swift?

Tags: ios, json, swift

We have a url which contains configuration data in JSON format. We need this data before any of the views are loaded and should persist throughout the app's life.

Where do we load the url? How can we store the resulting NSDictionary statically?

In Java, for example, I would create a Singleton and just have a static property with getters/setters. Is there a way I can do this with Swift or is there a different recommended way to store data in iOS?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, singletons can be created in Swift:

```
private let _SomeManagerSharedInstance = SomeManager()

class SomeManager {
    class var sharedInstance: SomeManager {
        return _SomeManagerSharedInstance
    }
}
```

http://thatthinginswift.com/singletons/

You might also consider storing the information on UIApplication's delegate (your AppDelegate file) which can be accessed by `UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate`